# automate keyboard

Tags: automation, keyboard

Is there a way to automate keyboard editing?

Yes I know I can write a program that will parse the text file to do the automation, however using an automation software is faster.

Is there a tool that can record keyboard strokes and "play" them again so i don't have to edit the same thing 5 times , and just do it once and run it 5 times.

simple example

```
more coade
more coaade
more coe3ade
```

change to

```
more code
more code
more code
```

where the marker is set to the first position of the second word in the line and retype it after deleting it.

Edit: its simple, is there a software to macro keyboard key presses?

Comment: If you write a program, that is program is software, right? In what way is other software faster? Or otherwise, what is your exact question?

Comment: I don't understand the question either... :-|

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notepad++ will assist you when editing text like this. You can either:

1) Use a regular expression to do a string replacement
http://markantoniou.blogspot.com/2008/06/notepad-how-to-use-regular-expressions.html

2) Record a macro and play it back several times.

- To do so. Go to: Macro > Start Recording
- Use the keyboard to make your changes in a way that it is repeatable
- Go back to Macro > Stop recording
- Play back your macro as much as you like

Although personally, I'd write a script in AutoIt or similar. That's probably the easiest thing to do if you have some programming skills.

Comment: the notepad++ is useful, however limited with the use of the clipboard where it starts messing the code.